# How to configure Search in SharePoint online for site not on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am new to SharePoint search. I want my web site to use SharePoint online search so that all content of my website is searchable by share point . My website is on different CMS. Where do I start. Do I need to add new content source in SharePoint search pointing to my website ?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the option to configure Content Sources in SharePoint. If you need the combined result set, implement a SharePoint 2013 or 2016 on-prem farm and use the [Cloud Search Service Application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt844716(v=office.16).aspx). The CSSA will allow you to search any Content Source you wish and upload the results to SharePoint Online. Searching in SharePoint Online will then show the results of all Content Sources in the CSSA.

Comment: Is it same for Office 365 as well? I cant not make use of my SharePoint search to search my website on another CMS or my any external website ?

Comment: Office 365 is SharePoint Online in the case you're talking about. SPO will only crawl itself. To inject other Content Sources requires you to use SharePoint Hybrid with an on-prem farm.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add new content source in SharePoint search , If you want to get all results (Both SharePoint Online in office 365 and SharePoint server) in search center ,  you need to configure hybrid federated search to achieve your goal .

https://technet.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/dn771045(v=office.16).aspx .

Comment: Was it possible in previous versions of share points ? What are my other options ?

Comment: See my responses below. It has answers to both of your questions.